Read file contents from stdin in radare2
I want to programmatically use radare2 via r2pipe, but instead of the usual method of opening files via their filepath:
$ python3
>>> import r2pipe
>>> r2 = r2pipe.open('/bin/ls')
>>> ...
>>> r2.quit()

I want to open them by letting r2pipe know of a byte buffer with file contents:
buf = ... # byte buffer
r2pipe.open(buf) # that's what I want

I know that I can open a temporary file, dump the buffer there, then load the file in r2pipe, but I want to avoid saving to disk since the byte buffer can contain malicious data.
It looks like radare2 has a flag for reading from stdin:
 =            read file from stdin (use -i and -c to run cmds)

but I am not sure how I can leverage it via r2pipe.
r2pipe just opens a process to radare2 and maintains it by sending commands and receiving the output, and the open command allows flags, here is its source:
https://github.com/radareorg/radare2-r2pipe/blob/c5281aefe8d304b3eafcae71fd1b4798371d00ee/python/r2pipe/open_sync.py#L72
